# How to send a JSON body in a get request with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm facing a problem since 3 weeks now, I'm using an API pretty particular which need a JSON object as body in a GET request. And I think that it's the main problem

I tried to custom my encoding with ParameterEncoding thanks the Alamofire documentation and all the help provide in Stack Overflow and still no success.

When I make my request with Postman or with curl in my terminal, there is no problem but when I develop in swift with Alamofire, I get an internal error 500 or nothing passed in my response (when I set my parameter in my request function with the keyword encoding : JSONEncoding.default).

Here is the curl exemple :

curl -X GET https://blih.epitech.eu/user/repositories
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'
-d '{"user": account, "signature": password}'

Here is the sample of my code :

```
/// swift 5
let userString = #"{"user":"\#(account)","signature":"\#(signaturePassword)"}"#
let urlString = "https://blih.epitech.eu/repositories"

Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .get, parameters: [:], encoding: JSONStringArrayEncoding.init(string: userString), headers: nil)
    .responseJSON { (response) in
        debugPrint(response)
}
```

The 'JSONStringArrayEncoding' is a structure with my Custom Encoding :

```
struct JSONStringArrayEncoding: ParameterEncoding {
    private let myString: String

    init(string: String) {
        self.myString = string
    }

    func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
        var urlRequest = try urlRequest.asURLRequest()

        let data = Data(myString.utf8)

        if urlRequest.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") == nil {
            urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        }

        urlRequest.httpBody = data

        return urlRequest
    }
}
```

I expect to have a json Array when the request is successsful :

```
{
"message": "Listing successful",
    "repositories": {
        "aaaa": {
            "uuid": "e3a6bea1-c581-5fde-a3a8",
            "url": "https://blih.epitech.eu/repository/aaa"
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an internal error 500.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried visiting your url in a browser? https://blih.epitech.eu/user/repositories

Comment: Of course, I sometime get the same error when I develop in Swift, but when I test with postman or a curl command, there is no problem. I should precise that you need to send an object in the body : {"user":"test@epitech.eu", "signature":"long-token"}

Answer (score 5):

Just replace `JSON.encoding` -> `URLEncoding`

```
Alamofire.request(path,method: .get, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

As you have mentioned that, your request is working using postman or curl in terminal. Below is the result I'm getting

[image]

As pointed by @Glenn, result of visiting browser with url  [blih.epitech.eu/user/repositories](https://blih.epitech.eu/user/repositories) show result like below

[image]

I believe, there is something wrong with the url you're requesting to.

**EDITED:**

See the below image to see the why it is working with curl

[image]

> Try your request as post once and add `content-type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded` I am not sure but it might help.

Comment: You should not expose your signature like this. It can lead to data breach.

Comment: Thanks, should I delete my post then ?

Comment: Delete your comment only, I believe that, -d in curl used for posting the data in post type request

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let url = "https://blih.epitech.eu/user/repositories"
let param = ["user":"asdfdsf",
    "signature":"password"]
if let jsonData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(param) {

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
    request.setValue("application/json; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = jsonData

    Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON {
        (response) in
        debugPrint(response)
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

> {
>      error = "Bad token";
>   }

Comment: I still get the 500 error : Status Code: 500, Headers {
    Connection =     (
        "keep-alive"
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        759
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Fri, 26 Apr 2019 07:23:21 GMT"
    );
    Server =     (
        "nginx/1.10.2"
    );
} }
[Result]: FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 5."